# Primality test bound: square root of n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization, primality-test

I was reading about primality test and at the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) page it said that we just have to test the divisors of $n$ from $2$ to $\sqrt n$, but look at this number:

$$7551935939 = 35099 \cdot 215161$$

Since $\sqrt {7551935939} \approx 86901,875$ so basically I would only have to check the divisors from $2$ to $90000$, but one of the divisors ($215161$) is greater than $90000$.

Also, do you guys have some ideas to improme my primality test?

Comment: A simpler example would have been $n=6=2\cdot 3$.

Comment: The other divisor is less than 90000, so you would have found it.

Comment: Do you want to only test for primality or also to exhibit a factor if you conclude that $n$ is composite?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you find the smaller divisor, you automatically find the larger divisor too.

Comment: And just to be super-explicit in case a future reader doesn't follow:  You have the equation $xy=7551935939$.  You just found $x$ by checking numbers under $\sqrt{7551935939}$.  Thus, we can find $y$. `:)`

Answer (score 8):

It's already been implicitly said by several people, but here is the explicit reasoning. Suppose that $n$ is not prime. Then we can write $n = ab$ for integers $a$ and $b$ which are both greater than $1.$ If both $a  > \sqrt{n}$ and $b > \sqrt{n}$ then we would have $ab > \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n} = n,$ a contradiction. Hence either $a \leq \sqrt{n}$ or $b \leq \sqrt{n},$ so if you check as far as $\sqrt{n}$ and don't find a divisor of $n$ greater than $1,$ then $n$ must be prime.